# Displaying current language layout in traybar

Tags: c#, c++, windows, windows-7, keyboard-layout

Basically I want to write an application which would display the current language as a tray icon. Mainly I can code C++ and C#. Guess Google would help me out but I would like to ask it here first, since the community, the knowledge here is something I trust.

(Never wrangled with such parts of the system so far. So that's why I would like to ask the community.)

Okay thanks to your help, I managed to discover two ways. Using the `DllImport` in C# (importing the `user32.dll`) and the `InputLanguage`.

Found a snippet:

```
public void SetNewCurrentLanguage() {
    // Gets the default, and current languages.
    InputLanguage myDefaultLanguage = InputLanguage.DefaultInputLanguage;
    InputLanguage myCurrentLanguage = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;
    textBox1.Text = "Current input language is: " + myCurrentLanguage.Culture.EnglishName + '\n';
    textBox1.Text += "Default input language is: " + myDefaultLanguage.Culture.EnglishName + '\n';

    // Changes the current input language to the default, and prints the new current language.
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = myDefaultLanguage;
    textBox1.Text += "Current input language is now: " + myDefaultLanguage.Culture.EnglishName;
}
```

I applied this like the following:

```
        InputLanguage myCurrentLanguage = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;
        notifyIcon.Text = myCurrentLanguage.LayoutName + '\n' + myCurrentLanguage.Culture.DisplayName;
```

This displays it if you hover it above the icon. However, it won't update on switch, nor show the layout as text in the tray area. For that, I found a "[Drawing in VB.NET](http://www.vbforfree.com/?p=302)" article, maybe this will help me working out this issue. About the switch detect, that's a good question.

Comment: Okay, if one gives a "-1", please consider telling me how could I improve the question. This issue is bothering other people also. Thanks.

Comment: How about you google first and attempt writing such a program, when you encounter a specific problem you can't solve then ask a question on here.

Comment: Because usually the answers on Google are written by unknown people. I would like to get a "start help" from someone who is trusted, who can code, and who knows what is he doing. (Anyway, my Google-fu is getting worse I guess because I can't find a solution there.)

Comment: What OS? Also, overall UI language or specific thread's language or keyboard input language?

Comment: Hi Shiki. (1) "Don't trust the people out there" is not a good strategy for development. Why not first read what you find and then judge whether you can trust that pieces of information/code? (2) Why not googling and "trusting" results from stackoverflow best? (3) With your approach to solving problems, stackoverflow would be supposed to replace the whole internet, which it's not intended too IMHO. (4) Read the FAQ: "Please look around to see if your question has already been asked (and maybe even answered!) before you ask"

Comment: Well that just makes you appear to be lazy. You must have found some information on APIs etc to use right? Some related sample code? What have you found and tried?

Comment: It's not like that. I always use Google, figure things out by myself. Since I didn't manage to find a clue through Google, thought I can ask the community (which was not a good idea I guess). 2) No, but I thought people here would have a solution, have experience with coding this and such question is a piece of cake for them. 3) I know. I am a Linux, BSD, openSolaris user (whatever I have to use) and since that, I really used Google A LOT.

Comment: @Gary - What have I tried: Googleing about all the Win API, about layout, etc. All I find is layout SWITCH through C#/C++ for example. Sadly all these threads are also old, outdate, not working. (But I do NOT want to switch, I just want to display it. Alt+shift is fine, but without global switch I'm just borked.)

Comment: @Gary - Okay, DLL export viewer + user32.dll ...maybe. GetKeyboardLayout maybe will help..

Comment: @Windows Programmer, cant you read tag of Windows-7, I guess if you havent heard, its Microsoft's latest operating system.

Comment: @Gary, what do you mean by specific problem, you have seen other questions here, like what is difference between private public and protected, I think SO community is loosing its good content by giving -1 to this question which is certainly a good technical question and having +4 vote for questions like difference between public/protected etc which are for programming babies, if you cant answer then no need to argue here.

Comment: Akash Kava, the tags "Windows" and "Windows-7" were not present when I asked that question.  Notice that the poster edited the question.  Notice that I posted an answer after the tags appeared.

Comment: @Windows Programmer, sorry about that, anyway your answer is cool.

Comment: Everyone: Sorry about telling it's Windows that late, somehow I forgot about that. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the user's overall UI language, `GetUserDefaultUILanguage`.

To get the current thread's language, `GetThreadUILanguage` or `GetThreadLocale`.

To get the current keyboard input language, `GetKeyboardLayout`.

To display a notification area icon in Windows prior to Windows 7, `Shell_NotifyIcon`. In Windows 7 `Shell_NotifyIcon` might still work if the user sets appropriate options, but otherwise you have to find another way.

If you have more than one possible keyboard input language, Windows already displays the current keyboard input language in the language bar unless the user has disabled it.  The user might put the language bar in the task bar, though it's not quite the same as being in the notification area.

If you want to receive notices when the user changes a language, `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` might let you know when you should call `SystemParametersInfo` to check.  I'm not sure if there's a better way.